# R data.table use variable name for assignment in group by

Tags: r, data.table, grouping

I am trying to summarize a data.table using a character variable as the name for the new column along with `by`.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(g = rep(1:3, 4), xa = runif(12), xb = runif(12))
# desired output
dt[, .(sa = mean(xa)), by = g]
   g       sa
1: 1 1.902360
2: 2 2.149041
3: 3 2.586044
```

The issue is that the following code returns the entire data.table still, without reducing to just the unique values of g.

```
cn <- paste0('s', 'a')
# returns all rows
dt[, (cn) := mean(xa), by = g][]
g        xa         xb        sa
1: 1 0.3423699 0.81447505 0.4755900
 2: 2 0.0932055 0.06853225 0.5372602
 3: 3 0.2486223 0.13286546 0.6465111
 4: 1 0.6942175 0.66405944 0.4755900
 5: 2 0.7225208 0.83110248 0.5372602
 6: 3 0.9898293 0.09520907 0.6465111
 7: 1 0.3523753 0.72743182 0.4755900
 8: 2 0.5504942 0.01966303 0.5372602
 9: 3 0.3523625 0.55257436 0.6465111
10: 1 0.5133974 0.39650089 0.4755900
11: 2 0.7828203 0.89909528 0.5372602
12: 3 0.9952302 0.16872205 0.6465111
```

How do I get the usual summarized data.table? (This is a simplified example. In my actual problem, there will be multiple names passed to a loop)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use `setNames` wrapped around the `list` (`.(mean(xa))`) column or

```
dt[, setNames(.(mean(xa)), cn), by = g]
#  g        sa
#1: 1 0.2010599
#2: 2 0.4710056
#3: 3 0.4871248
```

---

or the `setnames` after getting the summarised output

```
setnames(dt[, mean(xa), by = g], 'V1', cn)[]
```

---

In `data.table`, `:=` operator is used for creating/modifying a column in the original dataset. But, this operator is different when used in the `tidyverse` context

```
library(dplyr)
dt %>%
    group_by(g) %>% 
    summarise(!! cn := mean(xa), .groups = 'drop')
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#      g    sa
#  <int> <dbl>
#1     1 0.201
#2     2 0.471
#3     3 0.487
```

Comment: That works! Seems like strange syntax compared to what I was expecting

Comment: @drj3122 as the same operator symbol is used in tidyverse and data.table, there can be confusion about the behavior

Comment: I should have added I originally tried `dt[, .((cn) = mean(xa)), by = g]`, which I thought is consistent with data.table syntax, but that returns `Error: unexpected '=' in "dt[, .((cn) ="`

Comment: @drj3122 names on the lhs of `=` doesn't get evaluated correctly.  If you use `cn = mean(xa)`, then the column name would be the literal 'cn'

Answer (score 8):

There is a pending PR which will make this kind of operations much easier,
[data.table#4304](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/4304). Once implemented in current design the query will looks like:

```r
dt[, .(cn = mean(xa)), by = g, env = list(cn="sa")]
#       g        sa
#   <int>     <num>
#1:     1 0.2060352
#2:     2 0.1707827
#3:     3 0.6850591
```

installation of PR branch

```r
remotes::install_github("Rdatatable/data.table@programming")
```

data

```r
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(g = rep(1:3, 4), xa = runif(12), xb = runif(12))
```

Comment: That looks so much more intuitive!